# Two-line text button in Compact Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I want to create a two-line text button in Compact Framework. I have used every idea in this thread but without success.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/626c21e0-369f-441e-b2f1-b51db633e38b

If I use `\n` or `\r\n` or `Environment.NewLine` I get squares.

I am using Compact Framework 3.5.

Any idea on how to make a two-line text box?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to set the button to allow multiple lines. This can be achieved with following P/Invoke code.

```
private const int BS_MULTILINE = 0x00002000;
private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("coredll")]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("coredll")]
private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

public static void MakeButtonMultiline(Button b)
{
    IntPtr hwnd = b.Handle;
    int currentStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
    int newStyle = SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, currentStyle | BS_MULTILINE);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
MakeButtonMultiline(button1);
```

([source](http://peterfoot.net/2007/07/27/multiline-button/), verified it works on a CE device)