# Vertical Text on Button control VB

Tags: vb.net, vertical-text

One of my buttons on a form needs to show vertical text like that:

S

T

O

P

I found solutions involving overriding Paint that seems too complicated for such a simple task. I tried this:

```
Private Sub LabelStopButton()
        Dim btTitle As String = "S" & vbCrLf & "T" & vbCrLf & "O" & vbCrLf & "P" & vbCrLf
        Me.btnStop.Text = btTitle
    End Sub
```

and also tried replacing vbCrLf with: vbCr, vbLf, Environment.NewLine - to no avail, same result: only the first letter "S" is showing on the button. [See image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKuC7VHfQexRlBCbW9lTmZIQlk/view?usp=sharing).

Using Visual Studio 2008 (this is an app for an old WinCE 6.0 device).

Any advice?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you stretch the button out vertically so there's enough space to display all the characters?

Comment: Buttons support multiline text. Just ensure your Button is acutally big enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiline text as the button label in Windows Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972077/multiline-text-as-the-button-label-in-windows-forms)

Comment: Thanks. 
I added a link to see the result - plenty of vertical room on the control (the first "S" even shifts up to make room...).

Comment: What is the target framework?  .NET Compact Framework 2.0?

Comment: Target framework: .NET 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a duplcate of an existing question

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7661057/2319909

Converted code for reference:

You need to set the button to allow multiple lines. This can be achieved with following P/Invoke code.

```
Private Const BS_MULTILINE As Integer = &H2000
Private Const GWL_STYLE As Integer = -16

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("coredll")> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowLong(hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("coredll")> _
Private Shared Function SetWindowLong(hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As Integer, dwNewLong As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Public Shared Sub MakeButtonMultiline(b As Button)
    Dim hwnd As IntPtr = b.Handle
    Dim currentStyle As Integer = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE)
    Dim newStyle As Integer = SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, currentStyle Or BS_MULTILINE)
End Sub
```

Use it like this:

```
MakeButtonMultiline(button1)
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct (green tick) - you dont need to change the title - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created vertical text on the button with the following codes :

```
CommandButton1.Caption = "F" & Chr(10) & "I" & Chr(10) & "L" & Chr(10) & "T" & Chr(10) & "E" & Chr(10) & "R" & Chr(10)
```

[image]

[Source of userform](https://eksi30.com/autofilter-in-sheet-with-the-userform/)